# How to get the MySQL query results into a List<String> in java

Tags: java, mysql, mssql-jdbc

I have SQL query which results in multiple rows and columns. 
I want to execute this query and get the results into `List<String>` instead of the ResultSet.

```
"select LectureDay, LectureStatus from lecturelist where LectureName like "Java%"; 
res = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

I want the results of the query in `List<String>`

```java
public static List<String> ResultList;
```

while statements look like this

```java
    while(res.next())
            {
                String LectureStatus = res.getString("LectureStatus");
                String LectureDay = res.getString("LectureDay");
            }
            res.close();
```

code:

```java
public void GetData(){
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB?serverTimezone=UTC";
String sql = "select LectureDay, LectureStatus from lecturelist where LectureName like 'Java%'";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
res = pstmt.executeQuery();
try 
        {           
            Class.forName(driver_name);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            while(res.next())
            {
                String LectureStatus = res.getString("LectureStatus");
                String LectureDay = res.getString("LectureDay");
            }
            res.close();
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }       
        finally {
                try {
                    pstmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    }
}
```

thank u for read this

Comment: Post the complete code

Comment: @OMiShah now i post that function code.  does it enough to figure out the problem?  if not tell me.

Comment: what you want like List<String> of LectureStatus or List<String> of LectureDay?

Comment: @yahitesh i want to add all of them in one list<string>. Or it's ok to store in separate list<string>

Comment: do you want it as one String list?

Comment: @Mafei yes! And  i tried ResultList.add( LectureDay), it's not working .

Comment: I think you have not initialized the static list.  You should initialize the static list before adding the data. have you done it ?

Comment: How would it help you to have both those strings in the same list? Your naming is off: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions

Comment: @Mafei i set list as static in class. But as u said initialized. Feel like i didn't.

Comment: if you are getting an error, please put it. then I will be able to fix the problem.

Comment: @Mafei sure i will tried and if i got error. I will post it

Comment: Other thing is that if you are using Java 8 or above, please use ```try-with-resources``` read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc it is easy to use and avoid the Resource leak.

Comment: @Mafei ok. And actually. I want to store them and post it in gui. Whatever thank u for suggest me that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void GetData(){
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB?serverTimezone=UTC";
    String sql = "select LectureDay, LectureStatus from lecturelist where LectureName like "Java%";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    res = pstmt.executeQuery();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver_name);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        while(res.next())
        {
            String LectureStatus = res.getString("LectureStatus");
            String LectureDay = res.getString("LectureDay");
            list.add(LectureStatus);
            list.add(LectureDay);
        }
        res.close();
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }       
    finally {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a wondering.  If i want to use static List<string> list. Does it work same way?

Comment: yes! but then you need to declare List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); outside the method.