# Get SQL Result as list of String

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

From Java I make this query to SQL:

```
protected EntityManager em;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from table2");
```

Now I need to save this query as List of String or Object (so without a POJO), but evrytime I get the andress of memory:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1d905cdf, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5e53d7b5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1d2f8f05]
```

Does anybody knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the MySQL query results into a List<String> in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129125/how-to-get-the-mysql-query-results-into-a-liststring-in-java)

Comment: That means you tried to print a value of type `Object[]`. Without actual code and a description of what you're trying to achieve, this is impossible to answer (maybe `Arrays.toString(...)` does what you want, maybe not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
`TypedQuery<table2> query = em.createQuery("select * from table2", table2.class);`
then get resultList :
`List<table2> myList = query.getResultList();`
This will return a list of table2 object.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment but as I said I don't have pojo class because I have to do this with a lot of tables and I don't want create to many pojo class with too many fields, do you have another solution please?

Comment: do you know how can I get the column names?

Comment: **Little edit to the previous comment:** you can juste create a class which contains the feilds that you will return in your query, without persisting it. This is what we call DTO. Your query should be like this: String myQuery = "SELECT new  yourDtoPackage.yourDtoName( t1.feild1, t1.feild2, t2.feild3 ... feilds should be here in the same order as they are in the dto class )  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 ....."; Then use myQuery like this Query query = em.createNativeQuery(myQuery  );

Comment: You can name columns as you like. You have only to pay attention to the columns Type : String or int ... you can get this from your database. For exemple the select close will return three columns : two string and one int. So your dto shoud be like this : `public class myDto {
 private String col1;
 private String col2;
 private int col3;}`  You have to add annotation **@Data** if you are using spring data.